# How to add padding to hint (label) of material design Outlined text field

Tags: android, xml, textinput, material-components-android

I want to add left padding to the top label of the material design outlined text field.

Imagine I wanted to put the label on the middle of the textInput field. is that possible and how?

please check the image below to see what kind of label I'm talking about

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to have the hint of a `TextView` be in the middle, only left or right depending on your language localization.

**EDIT:**
With that said, why not try to add preceding/succeeding blank spaces (spacebar characters) in order to sort of hack the alignment of the hint inside your `TextView`?

E.g., if you want your text aligned to the left, add the following to your XML

```xml
android:gravity="start"
android:hint="  This is my hint"
```

Otherwise, of you want your text aligned to the right

```xml
android:gravity="end"
android:hint="This is my hint   "
```

Note: I added three spaces just to emphasize the empty spaces inside the hint, but you can play around with the right amount for you, ofc.

Comment: yea thx for the info. I don't want it in the middle exactly, just wanted to give some left margin so the hint is not that close to the left border of the text box.

Comment: @PedroSantos in that case, have you tried adding preceding/succeeding blank spaces? i.e. `"   This is my hint  "`. This is definitely a hack, but when in doubt... I'll edit my answer to reflect this idea.

Comment: yea i tried that but the hint white background convers the box line right from the start, soo the line box outline is not visible in that blank space and looks weird, it kinda works, it pushes the text to where I want but the box looks wrong.

Comment: Yes well, as mentioned, this is definitely a hack and I wouldn't expect it to work gloriously :/ but hopefully, it helps you approach a the look you're looking for. I'd love it if you could mark my answer as useful or even accept it if you end up finding what you want thru it!

Answer (score 0):

You can add padding to the start/left to the `TextInputEditText`

```
android:paddingStart="30dp"
android:paddingLeft="30dp"
```